# floating div with table-cell issue

Tags: css, html

I try to have to div floating side by side.

I have found a solution that work only with text :
http://jsfiddle.net/Sy392/2/

For that, i'm using table-cell :

```
.dablock {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

But if there is an image that replace the text, the "floating" effect doens't work.
http://jsfiddle.net/Sy392/1/

Thanks you for your help :)

Comment: You mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Sy392/4/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to .dablock

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
vertical-align: top;
```

On the `img` tag. By default, images flow the text directly at the bottom of the picture.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sy392/5/